# Exibir array de "filhos" de acordo com array de "pais" (JS)

Tags: javascript, json, array, react

Supondo que eu tenha o seguinte JSON, e queira transformar essas informações em componentes HTML (No meu caso, estou utilizando React), o que eu devo fazer?

```
 [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Pai1",
        "filhos": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Filho1"
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "nome": "Filho2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome":"Pai2"
        "filhos": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "nome":"Filho1"
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "nome":"Filho2"
          },
        ]
      }
    ];
```

1. A ideia é criar Tabs para cada PAI
2. O conteúdo de cada Tab serão Cards para cada FILHO do respectivo PAI

Eu tentei usando um for loop semelhante ao seguinte:

```js
var renderizar_pais = [];
var renderizar_filhos = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < pais.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < pais[i].filhos.length; j++) {
   renderizar_filhos.push(
   <div>
      <Card title={pais[i].filhos[j].nome}></Card>
   </div>
   }
       renderizar_pais.push(<Tab title={pais[i].nome}></Tab>)
)
}
```

Posteriormente eu "chamei" as vars "renderizar_pais" e "renderizar_filhos" dentro dos componentes JSX que eu queria renderizar, Porém, o problema é que ao fazer isso, eu estava inserindo TODOS os filhos nos componentes de TODOS os pais, e não apenas ao qual eles pertecem (isso porque estava fazendo o loop para os dois, um dentro do outro).

Desde já, agradeço quem tenha uma solução para esse problema, pois já tentei de várias formas e não estou conseguindo destravar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monte já cada Tab com os Cards correspondentes em um único array de componentes React.

```
const dados = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Pai1",
    "filhos": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Filho1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nome": "Filho2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome":"Pai2",
    "filhos": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nome":"Filho3"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "nome":"Filho4"
      },
    ]
  }
];

class Tab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><h1>{this.props.title}</h1></div>
  }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div><h2>{this.props.title}</h2></div>
  }
}

class App extends React.PureComponent {

  renderFilhos(filhos) {
    return filhos.map(filho => <Card title={filho.nome}></Card>);
  }

  renderTab(pai){
    return <div><Tab title={pai.nome}></Tab>{this.renderFilhos(pai.filhos)}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    return dados.map(pai => this.renderTab(pai));
  }

}
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-kilby-dxyly).

Comment: Muito obrigado, mari! Ainda estou trabalhando dessa forma pois eu resumi bastante o real problema nesse post. Porém, tenho certeza que vai funcionar. Entendi bem a lógica, ajudou bastante!